# 'resource' property value is not refreshing

Tags: spring

**//Jobs.xml**

```
<bean id="deptartmentReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">        
       <property name="resource" value="file:C:\TO-DEV\dept.data" />    
       <property name="lineMapper" ref="deptLineMapper" />      
    </bean>
```

**//tasklet.java**

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Jobs.xml");
```

While i run this java file from unix script, i am getting below **error**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): URL [file:C:\TO-DEV\OHM-Utils\dept.data]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:250)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
        ... 15 more
```

Please provide suggestions on this...

Comment: Consider formatting your code correctly..

Comment: I have given the value 'file:C:\TO-DEV\dept.data' to resource property in xml. But in error its saying 'file:C:\TO-DEV\OHM-Utils\dept.data' does not exist. It meants that reource value is not refreshing properly?

Comment: @user2160534 I suppose the problem is in your path. Try to write `new File().getAbsolutePath()` and check if you miss some folder, slash etc.

Comment: did you get any solution to this problem?